# Nitro unable to init or start after Docker update

Tags: nitro, docker

I did an update of Docker and to my surprise all my containers/images/etc were gone. So I figured I simply needed to init and start nitro again.

When attempting to start or init it keeps resulting in errors such as:

```
unable to pull from docker hub context deadline exceeded
```

I'm not sure what's keeping it stuck. I've tried updating multiple commands with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going crazy for half a day I found the answer to this issue and I'm sharing hoping others don't go through the same.

Turns out nitro still had knowledge of the previous installs (I suppose) and all I needed to do was run `nitro destroy`. I found out after almost uninstalling nitro altogether.